# How to create an MPLClassifier from weights and biases? (Python 3)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to create an MPLClassifier with predefined weights and biases so that I can save them to a file and then

If I train the network like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

data = np.load("data.npy")
labels = np.load("labels.npy")

clf = MLPClassifier()
clf.fit(data, labels)

np.save("weights.npy", clf.coefs_)
np.save("biases.npy", clf.intercepts_)
```

and then access the weights an biases like this:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

weights = np.load("weights.npy")
biases = np.load("biases.npy")
```

I want to be able to create a new network like:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(weights=weights, biases=biases)
```

Comment: It's not possible the way you want it. Just use pickle to save `clf` after training. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Plagon commented, you can't create an MLPClassifier from weights and biases.
Instead, you should import pickle and use it like:

```
with open("network.pkl", "wb") as network:
    pickle.dump(clf, network)
```

and access it like:

```
with open("network.pkl", "wb") as network:
    clf = pickle.load(network)
```

For more information on pickle you can go its documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html.